# mod re-write rule doesnt work

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have got this code:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule (.*)\.php review.php?site=$1 [L]
```

I want to get from this:

```
http://m.example.com/sandbox/mates.php
```

to this:

```
http://m.example.com/sandbox/review.php?site=mates
```

But it doesnt work.. notice that my htaccess root file is inside a directory and not in the root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your root .htaccess if you have one could be causing a conflicting issue for you.

Also you might want to change your rule to

`RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ review\.php?site=$1 [L]`

You can also be even more explicit:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ /sandbox/review\.php?site=$1 [L]`